# Why is HAXM failing to install with notice "Failed to update status to COMPLETE"?

Tags: android-studio, intel-haxm

I'm trying to install HAXM for Android Studio to use for emulator using the SDK Manager and this appeared.

```
Packages to install: 
- Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager)

Preparing "Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.5.1)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/haxm-windows_v7_5_1.zip
"Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.5.1)" ready.
Installing Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) in C:\Users\hamue\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager
"Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.5.1)" complete.
Failed to update status to COMPLETE
"Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.5.1)" failed.
Failed packages:
- Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager)
```

SDK Manager wasn't installed as the Android Studio said and if I tried to run an emulator, it shows `Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD.
Unknown Error`
`Please file a bug against Android Studio.`

How do I fix this?

I tried using both Android Studio 3.5 beta-4 and 3.4.1 and both of them failed.

```
Windows 10 Pro 1903
Intel Core i5-8250U
Hyper-V disabled
```

Comment: it is the same question as below topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60544578/android-intel-x86-emulator-accelerator-haxm-installer-revision-7-5-6-upda